# How to access property from another class?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I have a newbie question. How do you access a property from another class?

In my program, I have a view in which there are three levels available: easy, intermediate and difficult. I have three buttons with tags  (I'm trying stuff, so I've called those buttons: try1, try2 and try3) and I have created an int that holds the tag of the button pressed. So, the h of my first file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *try3;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *try2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *try1;

@property int level;


-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
```

the method in the m file:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {

   self.level = [sender tag];
    NSLog(@"tag is %d", self.level);
    }
```

Now, in my other view controller, I want to access the property "level" to change something, like so:

```
if (level == 0) {  do somtething


}

if (level == 1) {  do somtething


}

etc...
```

Comment: This is object-oriented programming. Do you understand the difference between class and instance?

Comment: A class is like a blue print, and an instance is an actual occurrence of that class?

Comment: @Dave "an instance is an actual occurrence of that class" that's a good start! Now recall what in order to access a property you need to know the instance on which that property is set. Property `level` belongs to instances of a particular class; your second controller needs access to an *instance* in order to get the `level` property.

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand that. Say for example my class was "RuralMachines", my object was *tractor, and my property was @property NSString *make... is that right? but in this case my they are all view controllers and that's when i get lost.

Comment: Me again. :) So, given what we've said so far, you need an instance to which you can send the `level` message. You need to be able to say `someInstanceOfThisViewController.level`. So now this problem is about _how to get a reference to the particular instance_ of the other view controller class. The instance exists, if it exists, _somewhere_ in the view controller hierarchy. That means you can access it. Getting a reference to some existing thing is one of the most fundamental OOP programming skills; my book has a section on it: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_instance_visibility

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this second view controller was presented by the first view controller, rather than trying to access the property of the first one, the second one should have its own property for `level` and the first view controller should populate that second view controller's property when it presents the second view controller.

If you search Stack Overflow for "pass data between view controllers" (or variations thereof), you'll find good examples. It depends a bit upon how the second view controller is presented (e.g. if you used a segue, you set the second view controller's property in the first view controller's `prepareForSegue`).

Comment: right, this is exactly it. ill look into it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a custom `init` for your embedded `viewController`, for instance:

**EmbeddedViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EmbeddedViewController : UIViewController

- (id)initWithLevel:(int)level;

@end
```

**EmbeddedViewController.m**

```
#import "EmbeddedViewController.h"

@interface EmbeddedViewController ()

@end

@implementation EmbeddedViewController {
    int selectedLevel;
}

- (id)initWithLevel:(int)level {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        selectedLevel = level;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

You will have to use this custom init from your `firstViewController`:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    self.level = [sender tag];
    EmbeddedViewController *evc = [[EmbeddedViewController alloc] initWithLevel:[sender tag]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:evc animated:YES];
}
```